# Java - load file from web context

Tags: java, servlets, filenotfoundexception, webcontext

I can't figure out why `fi.exists()` returns false here. I can browse to the file via the browser at `contextPath+"/images/default.png`

```
String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
File fi = new File(contextPath+"/images/default.png");
exists = fi.exists();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than getContextPath(), I needed to use getRealPath():

```
String path = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/default.png");
File fi = new File(path);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you missunderstood what the context path is.

If you application is deployed on `yourdomain.com/app`, the context path will be `/app`.

It is used to tell the client where to look for resources.

When you do `contextPath+"/images/default.png"`, you the path would be dependent of the deployment path (in this case it would be the file `/app/images/default.png`).

If you want the file next to the installation of your application server, you can use `"images/default.png"`.

If you want to access resource files, you may want to try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("images/default.png")` instead of files.

If you want to check if a context related resource exist, you can do it [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817033/10871900):

```
boolean exists=req.getServletContext().getResource("images/default.png")!=null;`
```

or

```
String path=req.getServletContext().getRealPath("images/default.png");`
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by 'next to the installation of your application server'. The image is not a resource, it's in the web context: `mydomain/app/images/default.png`. I tried your suggestion but still get file not found: `File fi = new File("images/default.png")`

Comment: Oh, this is what you meant. The things in the context aren't necessarily files. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I had to use `getRealPath`: `String path = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/default.png")`
File fi = new File(path);
This doesn't compile: boolean exists=req.getServletContext().getResource("images/default.png");